# Edit the record in same visualforce page in single row when EDIT button Clicked

Tags: visualforce, inlineeditsupport

I have displayed list of records in visualforce page and each record having EDIT and DELETE buttons. When i click on EDIT button i want to edit that particular record in the same page in single line edit formate.

Can any one assist me as how to edit the single row based on record ID when I Click on  Edit Button on the same visualforce page.

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at [apex:InlineEditSupport](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inlineEditSupport.htm)?

Comment: Yes Bar, I have tried with InlineEditSupport and also popup window..Its working fine.

Comment: If you add the code you have so far it will help people understand your issue and give you a better answer.

Comment: @ Mural : Were you able to find any links for this req, i have the same development to do? Please help